# How to create custom relation table for ForeignKey or OnetoOne field?

Tags: django, django-models

What I want to do is create a model than can be used to store data about a relation between two elements. With ManytoMany fields, I can use the parameter "through" and specify a model which stores two elements foreign keys as below.

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    relation = models.ManyToManyField('AnotherModel', through='RelationModel')

def RelationModel(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey('MyModel')
    model2 = models.ForeignKey('AnotherModel')
    slug = models.CharField()
```

What would be the equivalent for a OnetoOne relation or a ForeignKey relation ? I've read the docs about custom managers and some posts on SO so in the end I'm quite confused and I dont know what is the solution. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this

```
from products.models import VendorDetails

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   user_location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
   vendor_category = models.ManyToManyField(VendorDetails, through="UserProfileVendorCategory")

class UserProfileVendorCategory(models.Model):
   user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
   vendor_category = models.ForeignKey(VendorDetails)
   location = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Comment: I dont understand, what is 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL' in your OnetoOneField ?

Comment: dont think like that,its kind of one filed

Comment: I've tried your solution but when I access the manager i got this error : 'ManyToManyField' has no attribute '_m2m_reversed_field_name'

Comment: `parent_version = models.OneToOneField("self",
                                       default=None, blank=True, null=True, related_name="children_version")

    version_up = models.ManyToManyField('Ensemble', through='Version_up', symmetrical=False, blank=True, related_name='version_up_set')

class Version_up(models.Model):
    element = models.ForeignKey(ContentType ,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    commentaire = models.TextField()
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('element' ,'object_id')`

Comment: I've almost got it working using your solution, but I'm stucked on this _m2m_reverse_name_cache thing.